# Undefined index: url

Tags: php

Criei uma função `php` que está me retornando um erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: url... on line 2.

Estou dando `$_GET` na `$url` de forma errada?

```
function getHome()
{
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    $url[0] = ($url[0] == NULL ? 'index' : $url[0]);

    if(file_exists('tpl/'.$url[0].'.php')){
         require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'.php');
    }elseif(file_exists('tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php')){
         require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php');
    }else{
         require_once('tpl/404.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu acho que é porque no url não existe nenhum parametro que se chame `url`. faça assim para testar: www.seusite.com?url=ola/hello. Basicamente adicione `?url=ola/hello` no final do url e veja o resultado

Comment: Entendi, ele não está recebendo nenhum parâmetro, por isso da o notice, teria algum modo de quando ser nulo a url auto preencher para "?url=index"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser verificar se existe ou não um parametro que chama `url` no url e, caso não exista este fica definido como index, então faça:

```
$url = 'index';
if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $url = explode('/', $url);

    if(file_exists('tpl/'.$url[0].'.php')){
        require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'.php');
    }
    else if(file_exists('tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php')){
        require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php');
    }
    else {
        require_once('tpl/404.php');
    }
}
else {
   require_once('tpl/'.$url.'.php'); // index.php
}
```